# Adding to a nested array in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a data object model like the following:

```
export class JournalEntries {
  id?: number;
  year?: string;
  month: string;
  link?: string;
  months?: any;
}
```

A sample data would be:

```
"journalentries": [
    { 
      "id": "2000001",
      "year": "2021", 
      "months": [
        {
          "year": "2021", 
          "month": "January", 
          "link": "Jan_Feb_2021"
        },
        {
          "year": "2021", 
          "month": "February",
          "link": "Jan_Feb_2021"
        },
         ...
        {
          "year": "2021", 
          "month": "December",
          "link": ""
        }
      ]
    },
    { 
      "id": "2000002",
      "year": "2020", 
      "months": [
        {
          "year": "2020", 
          "month": "January", 
          "link": "Jan_Feb_2020"
        },
        {
          "year": "2020", 
          "month": "February",
          "link": "Jan_Feb_2020"
        },
        ...
        {
          "year": "2020", 
          "month": "December",
          "link": "Dec_2020"
        }
      ]
    },
 ]
```

My problem is, I can't seem to add a new month data to the nested array in the appropriate year. So if I add 2021, May, and some_link in the text boxes in the HTML part, it doesnt add it to the nested array. it adds it to the Main array. Which makes sense because this is what I have in the saveJournals click event

```
  this.journals.unshift( //putting it on the journals array
    {
      year: this.selectedRowData.year,
      month: this.selectedRowData.month,
      link: this.selectedRowData.link
    }
  )
```

So I get why it's doing that. But the following is coming up with an error

```
  this.journals.months.unshift( //Same with this.journals[].months.unshift
    {
      year: this.selectedRowData.year,
      month: this.selectedRowData.month,
      link: this.selectedRowData.link
    }
  )
```

I understand this could be a combination of problems, but I'm hoping someone knows the solution even with the vague data.

My expected goal is, if year already exist, add (year, month, link) to its months array else create year with new months array. Shooot! I'd be happy if you can help me with the unshift part only!

Comment: Well, you really should type `months` to be `{ year: string, month: string, link: string }[]` rather than `any`, but I digress. What we need to know is how does `this.journals` match up with `journalentries` in your data? Perhaps you could help by putting together a [mre] using Stack Snippets (icon is `<>` in the toolbar)?

Comment: I tried. There are some many dependencies and moving parts. But I can try. The model and data match is in my OP. I can manage the delete and edit. But I can't add for the life of me

Comment: Note the "minimal" part there; for this question, you probably don't need Angular, for instance.

Comment: can you share the error message please?

Comment: @MarikIshtar Property 'months' does not exist on type 'JournalEntries[]'. But if I add [0] as you suggested it spushes it to the first array only. So the data transfer and model is working. It's the array handling that I am not figuring out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this solution, I loop through the journal entries until I find the year I am looking for, then I modify the existing entry using `unshift` to prepend the selected month and link.

```js
const journalentries = [
  { 
    "id": "2000001",
    "year": "2021", 
    "months": [
      {
        "year": "2021", 
        "month": "January", 
        "link": "Jan_Feb_2021"
      },
      {
        "year": "2021", 
        "month": "February",
        "link": "Jan_Feb_2021"
      },
      {
        "year": "2021", 
        "month": "December",
        "link": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  { 
    "id": "2000002",
    "year": "2020", 
    "months": [
      {
        "year": "2020", 
        "month": "January", 
        "link": "Jan_Feb_2020"
      },
      {
        "year": "2020", 
        "month": "February",
        "link": "Jan_Feb_2020"
      },
      {
        "year": "2020", 
        "month": "December",
        "link": "Dec_2020"
      }
    ]
  },
];

const selectedYear = '2021';
const selectedMonth = 'May';
const selectedLink = 'May_Aug_2021';
journalentries.forEach(entry => {
  if (entry.year==selectedYear) {
    entry.months.unshift({
      year: selectedYear,
      month: selectedMonth,
      link: selectedLink
    });
  }
});
console.log(journalentries);
```

Comment: BOOYAHHH!!!! You nailed it! Now I just have to create the year if it doesn't exist hahaha. Buy yourself a beer on me!

Answer (score 1):

Check this, I hope it helps you somehow:

```js
const journalentries = [
    { 
      "id": "2000001",
      "year": "2021", 
      "months": [
        {
          "year": "2021", 
          "month": "January", 
          "link": "Jan_Feb_2021"
        },
        {
          "year": "2021", 
          "month": "February",
          "link": "Jan_Feb_2021"
        },
        {
          "year": "2021", 
          "month": "December",
          "link": ""
        }
      ]
    },
    { 
      "id": "2000002",
      "year": "2020", 
      "months": [
        {
          "year": "2020", 
          "month": "January", 
          "link": "Jan_Feb_2020"
        },
        {
          "year": "2020", 
          "month": "February",
          "link": "Jan_Feb_2020"
        },
        {
          "year": "2020", 
          "month": "December",
          "link": "Dec_2020"
        }
      ]
    },
 ]
 
 journalentries[0].months.unshift({
          "year": "2077", 
          "month": "December",
          "link": "Dec_2077"
        })
        
console.log("journalentries >> ", journalentries)
```

Comment: The OP wants to be able to add to any year. Your code will only add to the first year in the array of journalEntries.

Comment: As daddygames said, this works to the first year only, though it is not entriely bad because these are journals that get added every month and hardly ever get added to prior years, but it could happen.

Comment: What would be swell is if somehow the array position could be dynamic to recognize which year I want to unshift it to.